# join 3 tables and retrieve associated objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

trying to learn rails 3 and joins with a side project and have encountered a join i can't quite figure out. here are the classes:

```
class Stuff
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :things
end

class Thing
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :stuff
end

class User
  has_many :stuffs
  has_many :things
end
```

this is sample data:

```
Stuff            Thing                     User
id|user_id|data  id|user_id|stuff_id|data  id
--|-------|----  --|-------|--------|----  --
1 |2      |n     1 |1      |nil     |m     1
2 |3      |o     2 |3      |2       |p     2
                 3 |3      |nil     |q     3
                                           4
```

would like to return:

1. all Users that have both an A AND B, to get User, A, B as a result,
   and
2. all Users with either an A OR B, to get User, A, or User, B
   combos as well.

the query on above data would yield this:

```
Stuff    Thing        User
--------------------------
nil      1|1|nil|m    1
1|2|n    nil          2
2|3|o    2|3|2|p      3
         3|3|nil|q    3
```

some inner joins like below could be done, followed by ruby to remove Users with only A's or Users with only B's that overlap the results of Users with A AND B.

```
User.includes(:as,:bs).joins(:as, :bs)
User.includes(:as).joins(:as)
User.includes(:bs).joins(:bs)
```

any ideas on how to do this all with a single join either raw sql or active record query interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a solution using Unions. Unfortunately Rails Relations don't support UNION but find_by_sql and paginate_by_sql can be used. Below is a trimmed down version of the actual code:

```
    all = User.paginate_by_sql(
    "SELECT u.id as u_id,
        s.id as s_id,
        cast(null as integer) t_id,
        s.created_at as created_at
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN stuffs s on s.user_id = u.id where s.thing_id is null
    UNION
    SELECT u.id as u_id,
        cast(null as integer) s_id,
        t.id as t_id
        t.created_at as created_at
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN things on t.user_id = u.id
    WHERE t.id not in (SELECT things_id FROM s)
    UNION
    SELECT u.id as u_id,
        s.id as s_id,
        t.id as t_id
        s.created_at as created_at
    FROM users u
    INNER JOIN stuffs s on s.user_id = u.id
    INNER JOIN things t on t.user_id = u.id
    ORDER BY created_at", :page => 1, :per_page => 50)
```